# Google Analytics API, apply saved Analytics filter to API query

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I am currently working with the Google Analytics v3 C# API and am trying to put together a very large filter that reflects a filter that my client uses within their Analytics account.

I have determined that the Filter data size is too large for me to create from scratch and send in my request.  Is it possible to apply the existing saved Filter that my client uses within their Analytics account?  I know the name of the filter they use.

Edit:
It looks like what I need is to be able to do is apply a saved segment.  Using [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), I can get the custom segment id.  But now I am getting an error saying that my user does not have access to that segment.  Any idea where to grant permission to segments for an api account?  Thanks.

Thanks in advance for your help.

JH

Comment: What does the raw HTTP request to google look like? Are you sure this is coming from google and not your web server/IIS?

Comment: It is a windows application and I was just looking into that.  I think there's a chance that it's coming from my application now.  It may be as simple as an App.Config setting.

Comment: Quite possibly. There are limits configured on this kind of thing all over .Net. Like I said, use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view the HTTP. Does it even produce a HTTP request?

Comment: Actually, I am seeing the request to Google.  Fiddler tells me that I sent 7,018 bytes.  And the response body has the error:
message=Invalid expression. Expression exceeds max size of 4096

Comment: So fiddler says your sending the request and what do you get back? Anything? It could be a limit on your proxy FYI too. It all depends. I can't see anything in the google docs about size limits

Comment: 7Kb is one hell of a HTTP request TBH...

Comment: Since Google is complaining of the request size, I suppose that leads me back to Question #1.  Is it possible to use an existing saved Filter?

Comment: Yeah like I said it's a good sized comma separated list that they are using in their filter.

Comment: This is what the Response body looks like:
JSON
     -error
          code=400
     errors
          domain=global
          message=Invalid expression. Expression exceeds max size of 4096
          reason=badRequest
     message=Invalid expression. Expression exceeds max size of 4096

Comment: That looks like a google error to me. So your right google obviously caps the HTTP request. You should edit your question to change the focus on what you want now. Unfortunatly I don't know the answer to using an existing report. My guess is yes, but I'm not sure how, sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try to refocus the question to strictly Analytics API.

Comment: In the UI  and through the Management API you can construct a [filter resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters) and associate that with a view. In the UI you can also create a segment and then use that segment Id in an individual request. [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#dimensionfilterclause) has a more sophisticated filter syntax which if you build up the filter you might be able to re-use in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Matt I will check this out.

Comment: @Matt, I'm not finding a whole lot of documentation on v4.  Could you provide an example or resource?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing. [Complete Analytics Reporting V4 Resource/Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet), [Samples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) Sandly there are no C# samples at the moment. but perhaps have a look at the [dotnet client library docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/) You can probably map the Java examples to dot net fairly straght forwardly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by granting my api service account collaborator rights in analytics and sharing the user-defined segment with collaborators.  Then added the segment using the API and segment id.